# Specific newcolumntype (for 'R') not working?

Tags: columns

Could someone kindly explain why the following works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabular}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ | L{3cm} | C{3cm} | r | }
    \hline
    A & B & C \\ \hline
    1 & 1 & 16384 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

But if I try to include the following, it fails(?):

```
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\centering}m{#1}}
```

Many thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: your all defined column types works, however, as they are defined, had not to be used in the last column in table. Any of them int this case will cause error (due to missing `\arraybackslash` or use `\\ ` for new lines instead of `\tabularnewline` ...

Comment: As Zarko hints at, `\centering` redefines `\\ `, and thus it fails in the last column, where you have a `\\ ` that should start a new row. `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` fixes that, as I believe is mentioned in the manual of the `array` package.

Comment: Thanks very much indeed Zarko and Torbjorn - it works now.